# Prepopulate the ComboBox using comma-seperated String

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-collection, powerapps-selected-items

The string looks like:

```
teststring = "Sunday,Monday"
```

[image]

In combobox's DefaultSelectedItems when I write like this, it works.

How can I make this kind of format dynamically using the above teststring (even when teststring changes to something else)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code worked for me:

```
ClearCollect(collectOutput,RenameColumns(Split(Teststring,","),"Result", "Value"))
```

To access the collect list I just wrote `collectOutput.Value` in DefaultSelectedItems Property